# What's difference between " It is too tiring to~" and " It is too tired to~"?

Tags: expressions

What's difference between " It is too tiring to~" and " It is too tired to~" ??

Answer (score 2):

- It is too tiring

This is in active voice, so it suggests that that the activity described by 'it' will tire us or is already making us tired.

> I never run, it is too tiring.

For the second:

- It is too tired

This is passive voice, so 'it' is not an activity because it has to be something that can receive the 'tiring' action. 'It' is probably a person or animal, and they have done some energy intensive activity and probably now want to sleep or relax.